# If it would be more stable if different jobs can run at different separated process in the same worker?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

From the Flink [runtime](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/concepts/runtime.html) we know that "Each worker (TaskManager) is a JVM process, and may execute one or more subtasks in separate threads"

That means there is just one process per TaskManager ,so if there are two jobs scheduled in the same TaskManager(meaning both of them running at the same process),  they would affect each other. That is to say the STW GC of one job  would also cause the pause for another job, and the fatal bug of one job which  caused the process termination would affect all of the other jobs, so why not let the different jobs running at the separated different processes to avoid the issues mentioned above?

Comment: I think the difference is threads share the same memory space.. With JVM memory consumption can get out of control easily: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/operarting-system-thread/amp/

Comment: Doing this is totally up to you, you can just run separate clusters for your job if you need them isolated from each other. Though operationally this is obviously a bit of a pain, but in effect if you are needing to separate out Task Managers for each job, you are creating new clusters any how.

Comment: It's a option, however it is not a good option, as it increases the complexion of administration.